# Java Android android content res Resources NotFoundException:

Tags: java, android, xml, android-assets

I developed an application Java Android and i have a problem :)

I want to load an XML file.

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream questionsFile = assetManager.open("questions.xml");
document = builder.parse(questionsFile);
NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("question");
```

The XML is located in the Asset folder but i get an  res Resources NotFoundException.

[image]

Thx for the help !

This is my XML file :

```
<questions>
    <question text='Qui est le réalisateur de blade runner ?'>
        <answer trueAnswer='false'>Stanley Kubrick</answer>
        <answer trueAnswer='false'>Steven Spielberg</answer>
        <answer trueAnswer='true'>Ridley Scott</answer>
        <answer trueAnswer='false'>Roland emmerich</answer>
    </question>
    <question text='Ou se situe le siège social de la société Facebook ?'>
        <answer trueAnswer='true'>Palo Alto</answer>
        <answer trueAnswer='false'>Philadelphie</answer>
        <answer trueAnswer='false'>Dallas</answer>
        <answer trueAnswer='false'>Boston</answer>
    </question>
    <question text='Combien de saison a durée la série X files ?'>
        <answer trueAnswer='false'>1</answer>
        <answer trueAnswer='false'>5</answer>
        <answer trueAnswer='true'>7</answer>
        <answer trueAnswer='false'>9</answer>
    </question> 
</questions>
```

In fact my XML is loading but this code :

```
NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("question");
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),nList.getLength(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Only work in Java not android.

Thank all for the answers

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Its working, with this code :

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
document =    builder.parse(assetManager.open("XML/questions.xml"));
NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("question");

textViewQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
                  textViewQuestion.setText(nList.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("text").getNodeValue());
```

Comment: can you please post your questions.xml code ?

Comment: i have test your code and it's working i think something going wrong on your questions.xml file can you please post content of questions.xml file ?

Comment: Would you post your LogCat or stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also face this problem create subdirectory in asset and put this file to subdirectory and givepath assetManager.open("subDir/questions.xml");

It will work..check it..

Answer (score 0):

Clean and build the app and then start your app again

Comment: I have clean an rebuild the app but i got the        E/AndroidRuntime(1962): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3 error again